# Update failed while updating & installing plugins in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I faced this error while trying to install a new plugin (Wordfence):

```
Update failed. Installation failed: -1.
```

[Error while attempting to install Wordfence](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ofcdv.png).

Later faced the same `Update failed` error while trying to update my plugins.

I think it happened after deleting the **Admin Menu Editor** plugin.

*Additional info: I am using Wordpress 6.1.1; I have FileZilla; My hosting server Eternalhost.net uses ISPManager.*

Googled this and found some results (even in Stack Overflow). Tried changing `wp-content/upgrade` folder permission to 644, 755, and 777. No result.

Tried inserting this `Define(‘WP_TEMP_DIR’, ABSPATH . ‘wp-content/’);` code inside `wp-config.php` file. No progress.

Tried restoring to my previous backup with **UpdraftPlus** where everything worked fine and had **Admin Menu Editor** plugin. Still no luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Got exactly the same problem on many of my WordPress instances. For me, it was a plugin that interfered with installation and updating on the sites.

Faulty Plugin: Starter Templates

I just found that they mentioned this problem in their release notes. If you have this plugin installed: Deactivate it and run all updates incl. the faulty one itself. That should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, mate. It worked. The problem was exactly as you said. They have updated the plugin, and I can see this message in the changelog:

> v3.1.26 – 22-February-2023 – Fix: Plugin installation from WordPress plugins dashboard fails when Starter Template is activated.

Lucky me.

Answer (score 0):

Happened to me too. It's the Starter Template plugin. Disabled the starter template plugin. Problem solved. Every plugins were updated.

Thanks for the tips guys.